# Laravel: is possible to send multiple POST at same time using file_get_content?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to send multiple posts and expects multiple responses too.

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.example.com';

$data= [{"o": "45","d": "30"},{"o": "56","d": "10"},{"o": "25","d": "11"}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to loop and make a call for every item in the array

Comment: this is PHP, not JS, that code won't compile

Comment: That string looks like json. As Berto99 said, that particular syntax is not PHP, but I'm guessing that's what the PHP is receiving from the POST request. That string will turn into an array of objects, which can be accessed with a loop

Comment: You can't issue POST using `file_get_contents`. Maybe use cUrl?